# java MultipartFile.transferTo return NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, nullpointerexception, xlsx

I try to import and parse an XLSX file in jhipster.
For that i use to lib ng2-upload-file for the front and apache poi / poi-ooxml for the back.

So when import from the front the file the back give me an NullPointerException
on the execution of this line :

```java
inputFile.transferTo(uploadedFile);
```

my back's code :

```java
**
 * REST controller for managing import file.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ImportResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImportResource.class);

    private ImportService importService;

    private Environment env;

    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private UserService userService;

    public ImportResource(UserService userService, Environment env, ImportService importService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.env = env;
        this.importService = importService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/import")
    @Timed
    ResponseEntity<ImportResult> ImportData(MultipartHttpServletRequest file) throws IOException {
        final Iterator<String> itrator = file.getFileNames();
        final MultipartFile multiFile = file.getFile(itrator.next());
        log.info("Received request with file {}", multiFile.getOriginalFilename());
        final ResponseEntity<ImportResult> returnValue = importFile(multiFile) ;
        return returnValue;
    }
    public ResponseEntity<ImportResult> importFile(MultipartFile inputFile) {
        User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get();
        final ImportReport importReport = new ImportReport(messageSource,
                Locale.forLanguageTag(user.getLangKey()));
        importReport.cleanReport();

        String fileName = "";
        File uploadedFile = null;
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;

        log.debug("REST request to import a file with resetData : {}");

        try {
            fileName = inputFile.getOriginalFilename();

            final RelaxedPropertyResolver pathPropertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "spring.upload."); 
            final String path = pathPropertyResolver.getProperty("path");

            uploadedFile = new File(DataParserUtil.geneSrvFilePath(path, fileName));
            uploadedFile.createNewFile();
            inputFile.transferTo(uploadedFile); // java.lang.NullPointerException: null

        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            importReport.addError(-1, null, importReport.translate("parser.file.transfert", fileName));
        }
    }
}
```

and my front

```js
export class UploadFileComponent implements OnInit {

  uploader: FileUploader ;

  constructor(
    private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let url = null ;
    url = SERVER_API_URL + '/api/import';

    this.uploader = new FileUploader({
      url,
      authTokenHeader: 'Authorization',
      authToken: 'Bearer ' + this.authServerProvider.getToken()
    });
  }
}
```

So i think the is in my front because my back test work and i haven't problem for that.
But i don't know what is the option he forget on my front

Comment: There are multiple places above the code which will throw NPE till you reach the point you marked `// java.lang.NullPointerException: null` Are you sure about the point in the code which throws the exception?

Comment: i debug that i have that stack trace :

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.write(PartImpl.java:107)

        at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.transferTo(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:302)

        at web.rest.ImportResource.importFile(ImportResource.java:84)

Comment: i found the solution

i replace this lines
uploadedFile = new File(DataParserUtil.geneSrvFilePath(path, fileName));
uploadedFile.createNewFile();
inputFile.transferTo(uploadedFile);

by this function and it's work 
public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException
    {    
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close(); 
        return convFile;
    }